# I want to make a table audit/shadow table only when the email column of my table is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

when i update one row (email) the trigger sends all of the data to the shadow table I only want the one row that was updated what am i doing wrong in mt trigger code below?

```
CREATE TRIGGER AspNetUsersEmail_trigger
ON AspNetUsers
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF ( UPDATE (Email) )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]([UserId],[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName])
SELECT Id,[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName] FROM AspNetUsers
END;

UPDATE [Elearn2].[dbo].[AspNetUsers]
SET Email = 'isaac@gmail.com'
WHERE [Id] = 'A1785377-E3BA-483A-8600-024CA5885951'
```

Comment: tag your dbms? is it micorosft sql server?

Comment: Seems, you need to deal with inserted and deleted virtual tables. Currently you copy all data from AspNetUsers to audit table

Answer (score 0):

you should use `inserted` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AspNetUsersEmail_trigger
ON AspNetUsers
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF ( UPDATE (Email) )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]([UserId],[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName])
SELECT Id,[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName] 
FROM INSERTED
END;
```

read more about these special tables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Note that this will still insert even if all columns have not changed but the row was present in the update. Otherwise you need to `EXCEPT SELECT ... FROM deleted`

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL you have to select the data from the table inserted.

The tables deleted and inserted exists in triggers and contains the deleted and updated / inserted rows.